# Content behind sticky header is visible in scrollable table

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, html-table, scrollable

The current issue looks like this
As shown in the picture, the content is still a little bit visible when it is scrolled behind the header. How do i solve this and make the content not visible when scrolled behind the sticky header?

[image]

```css
.tableUpdates {
        overflow-y: auto;
        height: 250px;
    }

    .tableUpdates thead th {
        position: sticky;
        margin-top:0px;
        top: 0;
        background: #DC3545;
    }
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4 pr-0 tableUpdates">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">

           <thead class="bg-danger text-light">
               <tr>
                  <th>Header</th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            
            <tbody>
               .....some rows
            </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: you can add  margin and padding of 0 in the universal selector

Comment: @ShayanKanwal the issue still persist on my side after adding margin and padding of 0.

Answer (score 7):

This is a weird quirk with `table` and `th` elements. If either element has a top border you will get this behavior. The border actually scrolls and doesn't stick, leaving that gap.

One hack is to override `border-top` to have width of 0 for both `table` and `th` elements.

CSS

```
#myTable {
    border-top: 0 solid black;
}

#myHeader {
    border-top: 0 solid black;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-4 pr-0 tableUpdates">
    <table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover">

           <thead class="bg-danger text-light">
               <tr>
                  <th id="myHeader">Header</th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            
            <tbody>
               .....some rows
            </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Of course, then you don't have a top border...

Comment: brilliant! doing `top: -1px;` makes the sticky header move a bit when scrolled. Border hack solves that issue.

Answer (score 4):

Move the sticky header a pixel or 2 in the direction content is showing. So, if the sticky header is showing content from the top. Just move the header a little bit up using `top` in css. This should move your header so that the content doesn't leak through.

Comment: How do you do this?

Comment: @MarcelWilson add `top: -1px` on th elements within sticky tables

Answer (score 1):

Without using position as sticky

Add class to the **th**

```
<div class="col-md-4 pr-0 tableUpdates">
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">

       <thead class="bg-danger text-light">
           <tr>
              <th class="sitck-nav">Header</th>
           </tr>
        </thead>
        
        <tbody>
           .....some rows
        </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Add css to class **stick-nav**

```
.tableUpdates {
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 250px;
}

.tableUpdates thead th {
    margin-top:0px;
    top: 0;
    background: #DC3545;
}
.stick-nav {
   position:'fixed' # fixed the nav bar positon
   z-index:999  # hide the content
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `top:-10px;` property to the `thead` element.

```css
.tableUpdates {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 250px;
}

.tableUpdates thead th {
  position: sticky;
  margin-top: 0px;
  top: 0;
  background: #DC3545;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4 pr-0 tableUpdates">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">

    <thead class="bg-danger text-light">
      <tr>
        <th>Header</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      .....some rows
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```